# Manage Categories page does not work properly

Tags: admin, category, forms, tabs, magento-1.9.3.2

When going to edit categories, the forms below the tabs will not show up.
While the page is loading, the form will actually be displayed for a split
second but disappears once the page has fully loaded.
This has happened before, and the solution was to delete the cookies and/or
browser cache.
This fix does now not work anymore. I have spend countless hours researching
issue, but with out success.
Any advice is appreciated.

Firefox console:

> Loading mixed (insecure) display content “http://website.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/grid-cal.gif” on a secure page[Learn More] c64a534a377bfd0bd489c70a9c034540.js:2048:28
>   Loading mixed (insecure) display content “http://website.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/pager_arrow_left_off.gif” on a secure page[Learn More]  c64a534a377bfd0bd489c70a9c034540.js:2048:28
>   ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined[Learn More]  c64a534a377bfd0bd489c70a9c034540.js%20line%20612%20%3E%20eval:1:1
>   unreachable code after return statement[Learn More]  c64a534a377bfd0bd489c70a9c034540.js:17869:4
>   Blocked loading mixed active content “http://website.com/js/blank.html”[Learn More]  ff8f148eab111d681708a973266943fa
>   Loading mixed (insecure) display content “http://website.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/pager_arrow_right_off.gif” on a secure page[Learn More]  ff8f148eab111d681708a973266943fa
>   GET http://website.com/skin/adminhtml/default/default/images/pager_arrow_right_off.gif [Mixed Content][HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1338ms]
>   Blockquote

Comment: Well you can start by giving some kind of error from you exception.log or system.log within you var/log folder

Comment: Hi, attempting to edit categories will not cause any errors to be written to either log.

Comment: I found that since we use https, there are still some items which are not being served via https. This prompts firefox to pop up a window where one can choose to disable protection or not. I see now that the error does only occur when protection is not disabled.

Comment: This leads to the next problem: How can I find in which files the hardcoded http links are referenced, so that I can change them to https?

Comment: what do you mean with items? products?

Comment: By items I mean parts of the webpage.

Comment: Change your urls in your system->configuration->web to https:// (make sure it always ends with '/' ). Let me know the result

Comment: I did that when we switched to https, but since then there are still some items served via http.

Comment: All url's that Magento itself creates are based on that base url. They only store the /.../.../.. behind it.

Comment: but this is magento 1.9